# Recording the mobile application scenarios using jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I am facing an issue while recording the script of a xamarin android application,configuration of mobile is also done,but i am not able to record.

I tried to record other mobile application which on xamarin platform only.I was able to record that.

When i checked in recording.xml in bin folder of apachejmeter,I could get the logs in the below way,
-

```
<responseHeader class="java.lang.String"/>

<requestHeader class="java.lang.String"/>

<responseData class="java.lang.String">Non-TEXT response data, cannot record: ()</responseData>

<responseFile class="java.lang.String"/>

<samplerData class="java.lang.String">CONNECT b-api.facebook.com:443 HTTP/1.1 </samplerData>

</sample>
```

Can anybody please help me with this?..

Answer (score 0):

You need to install JMeter's certificate on the mobile device in order to let JMeter to decrypt and record HTTPS traffic

1. Locate `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file (it's being generated under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you launch [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder))
2. Transfer it to your device somehow (i.e. send it to yourself by email)
3. Open the `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` on the device (i.e. click at the email attachment) and follow Android certificate installation wizard to install it.
4. Once done you should be able to record secure traffic.

In general I don't think you should be even recording requests targeting Facebook API as you can easily get banned if you will be hitting the endpoint with multiple threads from single IP address so I'd rather suggest filtering requests to Facebook out using `URL Patterns to Exclude` input of the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder

[image: JMeter exclude domain from recording]

---

As a last resort you can consider switching to cloud-based proxy service, this way you won't have to worry about proxies and SSL certificates. As a bonus you will get possibility to export the recording in "SmartJMX" mode with automatic detection and correlation of all dynamic parameters, check out [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for more details.

Comment: I have already installed Certificate to my device still i am not able to record it.Is there any other way?..I dont know why i am facing this issue!!